# How to replicate a sentence with line breaks in between with an NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsstring, uilabel

I was replacing some old `UIWebViews` with `UILabels` and I realized that I had a string that looked like the following :

```
NSString * eaten = YOU ATE <b>%@</b> FROM %.
```

This sentence was being called in the following way :

```
NSString *warning = [NSString stringWithFormat:eaten, "CAKE", "JANINE"];
```

This was displayed as :

```
YOU ATE
CAKE
FROM JANINE.
```

Which is how I want it to be displayed. How do I now add the line break for the NSString though?

I've tried the following and they all did not work :

```
NSString *warning = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r%@\r%@",eaten, "CAKE", "JANINE"];
NSString *warning = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n%@",eaten, "CAKE", "JANINE"];
NSString *warning = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n%@\r\n%@",eaten, "CAKE", "JANINE"];
```

and

```
self.warningLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

But the output comes off as :

```
You sent %@ to %@.
```

What do I do here?

Comment: Umm... <b></b> bolds the included text, it doesn't generate line breaks (<br> does that)  But assuming your original string is just mistyped, you should replace <br> with \n.  In your test case, your repeating the eaten argument, it should just be `[NSString stringWithFormat:eaten, @"CAKE", @"JANINE"];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either change the `eaten` string directly (easiest and cleanest) or add newlines around the middle one

```
NSString *warning = [NSString stringWithFormat:eaten, @"\nCAKE\n", @"JANINE"];
```

If it's a variable you'll need to use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@\n", middleVar]` to construct it.

Either way, it's a bad idea to get a format from a variable like that. Use a literal directly so the compiler can check the argument numbers and types for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [backslashes](http://fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/5c) `\n` instead of forward [slashes](http://fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2f) `/n`.

```
NSString *warning = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n%@",eaten, "CAKE", "JANINE"];
```

---

**Update**

Oh, you have two format strings. That's no good.

```
NSString *eaten2 = @"YOU ATE\n%@\nFROM %@.";
NSString *warning = [NSString stringWithFormat:eaten2, "CAKE", "JANINE"];
```

Don't forget to make your label's height tall enough for the three lines and set `numberOfLines` to 0.

Comment: Updated Question. Sorry for that. But that's not it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"YOU ATE\n%@\nFROM %@.", "CAKE", "JANINE"];
```

If you want to reuse format:

```
NSString *eaten = @"YOU ATE\n%@\nFROM %@.";
[NSString stringWithFormat:eaten, "CAKE", "JANINE"];
```